# wp8.1 runtime: how to make gridview items flow first right, then bottom?

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

In the default Hub template, the gridview items go first bottom, then right. 
For example:

```
1 3 5 7
2 4 6 8
```

But in this way, if there are many images the Hub becomes very long to scroll, and it takes too much time to reach section 2.
How to make them float this way?

```
1 2 
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

I think this part must be edited, but I don't know how:

```
<GridView ...
          ...>
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</Gridview>
```

Comment: Change `<ItemsWrapGrid />` to `<ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="2"/>` or might have to replace the Maximum thing with just a MaxWidth to set your boundary for where to invoke the Wrap

Answer (score 1):

Just remove that altogether.  The default behavior for GridView is to go across and then down:

```
<StackPanel Width="350" Height="300" Background="AliceBlue">
  <GridView Background="BurlyWood" x:Name="MyGridView"/>
</StackPanel>

 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> MyList = new List<string>();
        MyList.Add("1");
        MyList.Add("2");
        MyList.Add("3");
        MyList.Add("4");
        MyList.Add("5");
        MyList.Add("6");
        MyList.Add("7");
        MyList.Add("8");
        MyList.Add("9");
        MyList.Add("10");
        MyList.Add("11");
        MyList.Add("12");
        MyList.Add("13");
        MyList.Add("14");
        MyList.Add("15");
        MyList.Add("16");
        MyGridView.ItemsSource = MyList;
    }
```

[image]

Then you just set the parent item (in this case, StackPanel) to exactly the right width in order to get the effect you want.

Comment: Why trade one Panel for two when you can just go set the orientation on the one he's using? The default is Vertical on the [ItemsWrapGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemswrapgrid.orientation)

Comment: I thought about that after I wrote that, but either way it works.